How to increase number of workspaces in Debian 12?
I have a Debian 12 system and am wondering how I can increase
the number of workspaces from 4 to N.
Executing this cmd echo $DESKTOP_SESSION returns mate.  So the DE is mate.

What is the desktop environment?

Executing this cmd echo $DESKTOP_SESSION, return mate. So the DE is mate.

Normally I press (alt)+(ctr)+(up-arrow)  and the system show us all the
working-spaces at the same time.
Now it is possible to:

select a working-space
remove a working-space (pressing the (x) in the upper-right corner)
or to add a new one (pressing the (+) in the right)


What desktop environment is this aiming at?

@JJoao, thanks for your answer. When I hit alt+ctrl+up, I don't see any x or + to delete a workspace or add one.
